# iPhone - Google Analytics user location

Tags: iphone, gps, google-analytics, location, analytics

I want to integrate Googla Analytics in my app.
I managed to integrate almost all the features but I don't know how to track the location of the users.

I need to know if it is possible and how to do it.

Thanks,
Andrei

Comment: what is your definition of "location"? IP address? GPS coords? zip code? City/state/region?  FYI tracking most of these things is against Google's ToS but even still, can't even begin to help unless you get more specific

Comment: Yes, it's possible. See [`CLLocationManager`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html).

Comment: I would like to use City and Country.
Is this allowed?

Comment: And I know how to use CCLocationManager, but how should I send the coordinates or city and country to Google Analytics?

Comment: assuming you work out whether or not it's allowed, you can send it in a custom variable. http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html

Comment: Thank you again. Hope it is allowed...I will find out and post here an answer for this matter. Best Regards!

Comment: Google Analytics does NOT allow location tracking.
Anyway, you have almost the same by default.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics isn't really intended for fine grain location tracking. A good and free platform for location tracking is Cintric https://cintric.com/ which includes city, county and much more.

Its a drop in SDK like google analytics. You then get access to a dashboard with all your users locations a a bunch of analytics / visualizations. It supports both background and while-in-use on android and iOS.

[image]